# kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT returns "/"

Tags: tlmgr, texlive-2019, kpsewhich

I am trying to update Texlive with `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` to tackle the problem below:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

But `kpsewhich` kept returning `/` and I have no clue how to get it to work.

```
$ kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT
/
```

update-tlmgr-latest.sh errors:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" ~/Downloads/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
[sudo] password for *: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

Output of `tlmgr conf`:

```
tlmgr conf
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
=========================== version information ==========================
tlmgr revision 53568 (2020-01-27 19:20:16 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2019
==================== executables found by searching PATH =================
PATH: /usr/local/texlive:/home/*/.nvm/versions/node/v16.9.0/bin:/home/*/anaconda3/bin:/home/*/anaconda3/condabin:~/.emacs.d/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/*/Code:/home/*/Code/alda:/home/*/Dropbox/code:.
dvipdfmx:  /usr/bin/dvipdfmx
dvips:     /usr/bin/dvips
fmtutil:   /usr/bin/fmtutil
kpsewhich: /usr/bin/kpsewhich
luatex:    /usr/bin/luatex
mktexpk:   /usr/bin/mktexpk
pdftex:    /usr/bin/pdftex
tex:       /usr/bin/tex
tlmgr:     /usr/bin/tlmgr
updmap:    /usr/bin/updmap
xetex:     /usr/bin/xetex
=========================== active config files ==========================
config.ps:        /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ps
fmtutil.cnf:      /usr/share/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktex.cnf:        /etc/texmf/web2c/mktex.cnf
pdftexconfig.tex: /var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/config/pdftexconfig.tex
texmf.cnf:        /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
texmf.cnf:        /usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
texmf.cnf:        /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
updmap.cfg:       /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap.cfg:       /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
============================= font map files =============================
kanjix.map:  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map
pdftex.map:  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
ps2pk.map:   /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
psfonts.map: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
ENCFONTS=.:{{}/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/*/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
SYSTEXMF=/var/lib/texmf:/usr/local/share/texmf:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist:/usr/share/texmf
TEXCONFIG={{}/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/*/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}/dvips//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{{}/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/*/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//
TEXMF={{}/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/*/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config
TEXMFDBS={!!/usr/local/share/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}
TEXMFDIST=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFHOME=/home/*/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/share/texmf
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/etc/texmf
TEXMFSYSVAR=/var/lib/texmf
TEXMFVAR=/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{{}/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/*/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
VARTEXFONTS=/tmp/texfonts
WEB2C={{}/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/*/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/*/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist}/web2c
==== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here) ====
```

Comment: `running on Debian, switching to user mode!)` that is the system texlive not the upstream texlive from tug, update it using `apt` as for other debian packages, not using `tlmgr`

Comment: "update it using apt" How do I do that? `sudo apt upgrade texlive`?

Comment: I managed to upgrade the system texlive using `sudo apt upgrade texlive*`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just wanted to say thank you. It took me over an hour searching for this until I bumped into this comment. Maybe worth to make it an answer, in the case others look for a solution?

Comment: General remark: It is possible to define some TeX internal environment variables, using the `$HOME/.bashrc` file. Such as `export TEXMFHOME=/path/to/wherever`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Sati mentioned as a comment to the question, `sudo apt upgrade texlive*` fixes that